# Angular 5 - Error in getting object

Tags: json, angular, object, observable

I'm new to Angular 5 , trying to display object from external API . Its displaying data but throwing error because of object type

json data from fixer.io

```
{
"success":true,
"timestamp":1529865488,
"base":"EUR",
"date":"2018-06-24",
"rates":{
  "USD":1.165473,
  "AUD":1.565348,
  "CAD":1.546355,
  "PLN":4.319264,
  "MXN":23.309846
}
}
```

currency.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { CurrencyListMain } from './currencyList1';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CurrencyService {

private _url:string = "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest";
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getEmployee(): Observable<CurrencyListMain>{
return this.http.get<CurrencyListMain>(this._url);
}
}
```

currencycomponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyService } from '../currency.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-currency',
template: `<h2>Employee List</h2>
          <ul >
            <li>success: {{employees.success}}</li>
            <li>timestamp: {{employees.timestamp}}</li>
            <li>base: {{employees.base}}</li>
            <li>rates: </li>
            <li>USD: {{employees.rates.USD}}</li>
            <li>AUD: {{employees.rates.AUD}}</li>
            <li>CAD: {{employees.rates.CAD}}</li>
            <li>PLN: {{employees.rates.PLN}}</li>
            <li>MXN: {{employees.rates.MXN}}</li>
          </ul>`,
 styleUrls: ['./currency.component.css']
})
export class CurrencyComponent implements OnInit {

public rates = {}
public employees = {};

constructor(private _currencyService: CurrencyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this._currencyService.getEmployee()
.subscribe(data => this.employees = data);
}
}
```

currencylist1.ts - interface:

```
import {UserRatesList} from './userRates' ;
export interface CurrencyListMain{
success:string,
timestamp:string,
base:string,
date:string,
rates: UserRatesList
}
```

userRates.ts  interface:

```
export interface UserRatesList{
USD:number,
AUD:number,
CAD:number,
PLN:number,
MXN:number
}
```

Getting this following error:

```
 CurrencyComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'USD' of 
undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CurrencyComponent.html:7)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10776)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10152)
at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10330)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
at callViewAction (core.js:10388)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10330)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10153)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11040)
```

How to get the object type in observable correctly

Comment: what is the signature of `data` return from serviceMethod? also you need to add typing for employee something like `employee: { [key:string] : UserRatesList}`

Answer (score 1):

Use the safe navigation operator ? :

```
        <li>success: {{employees?.success}}</li>
        <li>timestamp: {{employees?.timestamp}}</li>
        <li>base: {{employees?.base}}</li>
        <li>rates: </li>
        <li>USD: {{employees?.rates.USD}}</li>
        <li>AUD: {{employees?.rates.AUD}}</li>
        <li>CAD: {{employees?.rates.CAD}}</li>
        <li>PLN: {{employees?.rates.PLN}}</li>
        <li>MXN: {{employees?.rates.MXN}}</li>
```

Comment: Is there another way to use one interface instead of 2. I used 2 interface files for describing the object.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not the compiler that complains, as the compiler will have no idea whether or not it's null. This is a runtime error, not a compile time error

Comment: @ user184994, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "employees?.rates" in your html.

The problem is that your html is rendering before your data is coming back and since rates is undefined, you can't access usd.

The ?. operator will check for null or undefined and return successfully.

Also, are you sure employees is not an array? Do you need to do an ngRepeat?

Comment: Yes ? operator solved my issue, Thanks . Im getting json from fixer.io to display currency conversion . its object , not an array.

Comment: If there is another way to get the object instead of interface, please let me know. Or any other way to get the api to display. I have seen some examples to display array but not the object type.

Comment: You don't need the interface at all.  That's just so typescript can give compiler errors and so you can use intellisense.  But you can use a class instead of an interface.  Not sure why you would want to, but you could.

Comment: ill try class, thank you. I just gone through some examples and tried my own, only this method worked but with errors like mentioned. Im learning newly.